# What does it mean to restrict a function germ to a set germ?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, germs

Two sets $S$ and $T$ define the same germ at a point $\xi$ in a topological space $M$ if there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $\xi$ such that $S \cap U = T \cap U$.

Two functions $f,g : M \rightarrow \Bbb C$ define the same germ at $\xi$ if there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $\xi$ such that $f \vert_U = g \vert_U$.

Given a function germ $f_\xi$ and a set germ $S_\xi$, what is the meaning of $f_\xi \vert_{S_\xi}$?

Comment: I would guess that it's an equivalence class of pairs $(S,f)$, where two such pairs agree if and only if there is a small neighbourhood $U$ where the sets agree and the restriction of the functions to the sets agree. Note that this is well-defined on equivalences of germs of functions and sets: first take a neighbourhood such that the functions agree, then take one such that the sets agree, and intersect them. Restricting does not change the fact the functions agree. But, to be honest, I've never seen that notation.

Comment: This definition seems natural, and I will check to see if it makes sense in the context of the problem I am tackling.  Thanks!